# Bootstrap Tooltip is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to show tooltip when hovering over a div that is located inside table cell:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div class="progress">
           <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" tooltip="tooltip1" tooltip-placement="top" class="progress-bar bg-green" ng-style="getPercentageAsStyle(assetGroup, 0)">My text</div>                                    
       </div>
       ....
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

For some reason, tooltip is not working (it is not over the cell, but it is rendered for the document). What mistake am I doing here?

Comment: you added the bootstarp css. and its will be great if you put a snippet of you code in stackoverflow runner

Answer (score 1):

You should do the `tooltip()` plugin on the `.progress` element.

You are using AngularJS so you need to move the attributes to the `.progress` element. In this case I just called the plugin manually.

Also, you need to add `title` attribute for the text's tooltip.

```js
$('.progress').tooltip();
```

```css
table {
  width:100%;  
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="progress" title="my tooltip">
            <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" tooltip="tooltip1" tooltip-placement="top" class="progress-bar bg-green" ng-style="getPercentageAsStyle(assetGroup, 0)">My text</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still not working. For some reason opacity of tooltip is always 0 and it is "under" other table cells

Comment: It's not make any sense. If you have `data-container="body"` on the element, the tooltip should append to the `body`. Can you create a working snippet or bin for this with all the relevant code?